# c# YAMLSerializer string value instead of int

Tags: c#, serialization, yaml

I need to perform this:

```
YamlNode[] nodes = YamlNode.FromYaml(variable);
YamlMapping map = (YamlMapping)nodes[0];
```

but if my variable contains Key with value that is more than int32 max, I'm getting the error "Value is too big for Int32".
How can I make it think that all the values contain string?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing single quotes around the number
aaa: '99999999999999999'

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding .ToString() like this?

```
YamlNode[] nodes = YamlNode.FromYaml(variable.ToString());
YamlMapping map = (YamlMapping)nodes[0];
```

Comment: Can you post the declaration and contents of 'variable'?

Comment: variable is a string contains "aaa: 9999999999999"

Comment: try aaa: '9999999999999999'